# XML Parse in Python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, xml.etree

I am working on a new Python script to parse XML out and am having troubles navigating to the right index. The script gets data from a .csv and converts the XML per row into a string, and I need to extract from that string. All the code I have tried comes up empty. There are only 4 pieces of information I need (marked by ****). Under 'Hotel Reservation ID' I am trying to grab ResID_Value and ResID_Source for both entries. Under 'TimeSpan' I am trying to get both 'Start' and 'End' but am having no luck. I have tried using indexes and navigating using root/OTA_HotelResModifyRQ/HotelResModifies/HotelResModify. Here is the XML:

```
<soapns:Envelope xmlns:soapns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
   <soapns:Body>
      <OTA_HotelResModifyRQ xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05 OTA_HotelResModifyRQ.xsd" TimeStamp="2021-04-01T05:00:23+00:00" Target="Production" Version="2.001" ResStatus="Commit" SequenceNmbr="1" TransactionIdentifier="xxxxxx" TransactionStatusCode="End" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
         <POS>
            <Source>
               <RequestorID Type="13" ID="WWWBC" ID_Context="xxxxxx" URL="xxxxxx"/>
            </Source>
         </POS>
         <HotelResModifies>
            <HotelResModify>
               <UniqueID Type="14" ID="xxxxxx" ID_Context="CompanyX"/>
               <UniqueID Type="14" ID="xxxxxx" ID_Context="CompanyY" Instance="1"/>
               <RoomStays>
                  <RoomStay IndexNumber="104">
                     <RoomTypes>
                        <RoomType RoomTypeCode="32458814">
                           <RoomDescription Name="Deluxe Double or Twin Room with Mountain View">
                              <Text>This modern room is on the fifth or sixth floor and  offers a private balcony overlooking the mountains. It includes a flat-screen TV, a DVD player and a minibar. The bathroom has free toiletries, a shower and a hairdryer.</Text>
                           </RoomDescription>
                           <Amenities>
                              <Amenity>Minibar</Amenity>
                              <Amenity>Shower</Amenity>
                              <Amenity>Bath</Amenity>
                              <Amenity>Safety Deposit Box</Amenity>
                           </Amenities>
                        </RoomType>
                     </RoomTypes>
                     <RatePlans>
                        <RatePlan>
                           <Commission>
                              <CommissionPayableAmount Amount="832" DecimalPlaces="1" CurrencyCode="OMR"/>
                           </Commission>
                        </RatePlan>
                     </RatePlans>
                     <RoomRates>
                        <RoomRate EffectiveDate="2017-03-12" RatePlanCode="1431301">
                           <Rates>
                              <Rate EffectiveDate="2017-03-12" ExpireDate="2017-03-13">
                                 <Base AmountBeforeTax="xxxxx" DecimalPlaces="2" CurrencyCode="OMR"/>
                                 <Total AmountBeforeTax="xxxxx" DecimalPlaces="2" CurrencyCode="OMR"/>
                              </Rate>
                           </Rates>
                        </RoomRate>
                        <RoomRate EffectiveDate="2017-03-13" RatePlanCode="1431301">
                           <Rates>
                              <Rate EffectiveDate="2017-03-13" ExpireDate="2017-03-14">
                                 <Base AmountBeforeTax="xxxxx" DecimalPlaces="2" CurrencyCode="OMR"/>
                                 <Total AmountBeforeTax="xxxxx" DecimalPlaces="2" CurrencyCode="OMR"/>
                              </Rate>
                           </Rates>
                        </RoomRate>
                        <RoomRate EffectiveDate="2017-03-14" RatePlanCode="1431301">
                           <Rates>
                              <Rate EffectiveDate="2017-03-14" ExpireDate="2017-03-15">
                                 <Base AmountBeforeTax="xxxxx" DecimalPlaces="2" CurrencyCode="OMR"/>
                                 <Total AmountBeforeTax="xxxxx" DecimalPlaces="2" CurrencyCode="OMR"/>
                              </Rate>
                           </Rates>
                        </RoomRate>
                        <RoomRate EffectiveDate="2017-03-15" RatePlanCode="1431301">
                           <Rates>
                              <Rate EffectiveDate="2017-03-15" ExpireDate="2017-03-16">
                                 <Base AmountBeforeTax="xxxxx" DecimalPlaces="2" CurrencyCode="OMR"/>
                                 <Total AmountBeforeTax="xxxx" DecimalPlaces="2" CurrencyCode="OMR"/>
                              </Rate>
                           </Rates>
                        </RoomRate>
                     </RoomRates>
                     <GuestCounts>
                        <GuestCount Count="2" AgeQualifyingCode="10"/>
                     </GuestCounts>
    **************** <TimeSpan Start="2017-03-12" End="2017-03-16"/>
                     <Total AmountBeforeTax="xxxxx" DecimalPlaces="2" CurrencyCode="OMR"/>
                     <BasicPropertyInfo HotelCode="xxxxx"/>
                     <ResGuestRPHs>
                        <ResGuestRPH RPH="1"/>
                     </ResGuestRPHs>
                     <SpecialRequests>
                        <SpecialRequest Name="smoking preference">
                           <Text>Non-Smoking</Text>
                        </SpecialRequest>
                     </SpecialRequests>
                  </RoomStay>
               </RoomStays>
               <ResGuests>
                  <ResGuest ResGuestRPH="1">
                     <Profiles>
                        <ProfileInfo>
                           <Profile ProfileType="1">
                              <Customer>
                                 <PersonName>
                                   <GivenName>francois</GivenName>
                                    <Surname>maire</Surname>
                                 </PersonName>
                              </Customer>
                           </Profile>
                       </ProfileInfo>
                     </Profiles>
                     <GuestCounts>
                        <GuestCount Count="2"/>
                     </GuestCounts>
                  </ResGuest>
               </ResGuests>
               <ResGlobalInfo>
                  <Comments>
                     <Comment ParagraphNumber="1">
                        <Text>** Genius Booker You have a booker that prefers communication by email</Text>
                     </Comment>
                  </Comments>
                  <Total AmountBeforeTax="52000" DecimalPlaces="2" CurrencyCode="OMR"/>
                  <HotelReservationIDs>
   ****************  <HotelReservationID ResID_Value="xxxxxx" ResID_Date="2016-12-10T06:13:26" ResID_Source="CompanyX" ResID_Type="14" ResID_SourceContext="324588"/>
   ****************  <HotelReservationID ResID_Value="xxxxxx" ResID_Date="2016-12-10T06:13:26" ResID_Source="CompanyY" ResID_Type="14"/>
                  </HotelReservationIDs>
                  <Profiles>
                     <ProfileInfo>
                        <UniqueID Type="5" ID="xxxxx"/>
                        <Profile ProfileType="1">
                           <Customer>
                              <PersonName>
                                 <GivenName>francois</GivenName>
                                 <Surname>maire</Surname>
                              </PersonName>
                              <Address>
                                 <AddressLine>123 main st</AddressLine>
                                 <CityName>paris</CityName>
                                 <PostalCode>75016</PostalCode>
                                 <CountryName Code="FR"/>
                                 <CompanyName>[Unknown]</CompanyName>
                              </Address>
                           </Customer>
                        </Profile>
                     </ProfileInfo>
                  </Profiles>
               </ResGlobalInfo>
            </HotelResModify>
         </HotelResModifies>
      </OTA_HotelResModifyRQ>
   </soapns:Body>
</soapns:Envelope>
```

I have been trying with xml.Etree. I understand how to grab the data once I can point in the right direction, but how can I get that deep in the subattributes? I realize this may not be much to go off, I apologize. If you need more info, please let me know. This is my first attempt at XML parsing, any guidance would be very much appreciated!!! Here is the code I am using thus far: (Nothing is printing out, it doesn't even enter the second for loop)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as Xet
import pandas as pd

file_path = xxxx

df = pd.read_csv(file_path, usecols=['Client Content']

for i in range(len(df)):
     xml_string = df.values[i][0]
     root = Xet.fromstring(xml_string)
     for TimeSpan in root.findall('./OTA_HotelResModifyRQ/HotelResModifies/HotelResModify/RoomStays/RoomStay'):
print(TimeSpan)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't see a question here. Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/354577)

Comment: I have updated it for you.

Comment: Please read [ask], paying particular attention to the part that says, "pretend you're talking to a busy colleague". We shouldn't need to deduce your question, and it isn't usually a good idea to be snarky to people who are trying to help you for free. Make it as easy as possible for us to help you.

Comment: You say "I understand how to grab the data once I can point in the right direction, but how can I get that deep in the subattributes?" but I don't understand the problem. If you can navigate into one element, simply navigate into the next, and so on. Can you illustrate the problem by sharing your code?

Comment: I have added what I have so far. It never enters the second FOR loop. When I try to use for child in root: print(child.tag, child.attrib) all that prints is {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Header{} and {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body{}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible to use lxml parser? It allows usage of XPath, which would make hob a bit easier:

```
from lxml import etree

# declare namespaces
ns = {'ns': 'http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05'}

# parse XML from string
root = etree.fromstring(xml)

# retrieve time span using xpath
time_span = root.xpath('//ns:OTA_HotelResModifyRQ/ns:HotelResModifies/ns:HotelResModify/ns:RoomStays/ns:RoomStay/ns:TimeSpan', namespaces=ns)[0]
print(time_span.get('Start'))
print(time_span.get('End'))

# retrieve list of reservation ids
hotel_reservation_ids = root.xpath('//ns:OTA_HotelResModifyRQ/ns:HotelResModifies/ns:HotelResModify/ns:ResGlobalInfo/ns:HotelReservationIDs/ns:HotelReservationID', namespaces=ns)
for hotel_reservation_id in hotel_reservation_ids:
  print(hotel_reservation_id.get('ResID_Value'))
  print(hotel_reservation_id.get('ResID_Date'))
  print(hotel_reservation_id.get('ResID_Source'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried using this and got a ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported. Please use bytes input or XML fragments without declaration.

Comment: After encoding the string to ascii it worked like a charm, thank you SO MUCH!